# VBA selenium <div button class span> tried to click click

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, button, click

I have this case where i cannot click the button.
It seems to be Span within span, how to use this on VBA?

```
<div class=" detail-section">
<span class="btn click-back">
<span> << Back to Fill</span>
</span>
<button class="btn click-primary">
<span>Create Detail</span>
</button>
</div>
```

i tried and it doesn't work

`Obj.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(@span, 'Create Detal')] ")).Click`

Comment: Try this line instead `obj.FindElementByXPath("//*[contains(@span, 'Create Detal')]").Click`

Comment: Also, I see incorrect spelling in the locator. It should be `Create Detail` I think, instead of `Create Detal`

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer and working fine now.

```
Obj.FindElementByXPath("//button[@class ='btn click-primary']").Click
```